# How to create/add dvd drive of iso in Xen Server virtual machine using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine, citrix, xen

I am trying to create a powershell script that will create a VM in Xen Server of desired configuration and launch the VM. In one of the step I have to create/add DVD drive of ISO. (network drive). I tried but am not able to find the powershell equivalent command to do so. I am able to add storage as the disk though but not able to create the dvd from where the VM will boot and load the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar solution [HERE](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/380673-mounting-iso-in-vm-issue-invoke-xenvbd-xenaction-insert/):

This is the code that helped:

```
Get-XenVM -Name vmName | select -ExpandProperty VBDs | Get-XenVBD | where {$_.type -eq "CD"} | Invoke-XenVBD -XenAction Insert -VDI (Get-XenVDI -Name "$BootISOName" | select -ExpandProperty opaque_ref)
```

Comment: I tried this. I don't see DVD device created in the console.